# Getting an Security setting exception while accessing a WCF service

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security

Following are binding configurations of my WCF service.

- Anonymous access: off
- Basic authentication: on
- Integrated Windows authentication: off !!

**support HTTP protocol .**

I am getting an following exception while accessing my WCF service:

**Security settings for this service require 'Anonymous' Authentication but it is not enabled for the IIS application that hosts this service.**

```
<system.serviceModel>

    <bindings>

          <basicHttpBinding>

                <binding name="MyBinding">

                      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">                           

                            <transport clientCredentialType ="Basic" />

                      </security>

                </binding>

          </basicHttpBinding>

    </bindings>

<services>

        <service behaviorConfiguration="WMWcfWebServiceLib.Service1Behavior"

          name="WMWcfWebServiceLib.WMWcfWebService">

              <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyBinding"

                contract="WMWcfWebServiceLib.IWMWebService">                    



              </endpoint>

              <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />

              <host>

                    <baseAddresses>

                          <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8731/Design_Time_Addresses/WMWcfWebServiceLib/Service1/" />

                    </baseAddresses>

              </host>

        </service>

  </services>

<behaviors>

  <serviceBehaviors>

    <behavior name="WMWcfWebServiceLib.Service1Behavior">

      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 

      set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->

      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>

      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 

      set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 

      to avoid disclosing exception information -->

      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />

    </behavior>

  </serviceBehaviors>

</behaviors>
```

Please Help!!

**Edit**

I am able to access the WCF service through the web browser with the following changes:

Changes the security mode to TransportCredentialOnly and Removed the Mex Endpoint, **but now as obvious I am not able to create the proxy on the client side.**

Please let me know where I am wrong ?

Comment: Is the service hosted in IIS?

Comment: How do you access the service? If your configuration is used it should only support HTTPS.

Comment: I want to support HTTP only, should I change my configuration then ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to support HTTP only your configuration is not used at all because `mode="Transport"` demands HTTPS. First find why config is not used (probably wrong type name in service element). Next change security mode to `TransportCredentialOnly`. But be aware that `TransportCredentialOnly` + Basic authentication means that HTTP requests will contain plain text Windows user name and password. In most cases such implementation will not pass any security audit.

Edit:

You can create proxy without mex endpoint if you still support `httpGetEnabled` in service metadata behavior.

Comment: I have done the above said changes. like set the mode to TansportCredentialOnly and I am using Basic authentication. The httpGetEnable flag is set to True. But still I am not able to access the service. However if I delete the Mex Endpoint the WCF service is accessible but I am not able to expose the metadata and hence the client will not able to create the proxy!! I am wondering which option only allows to retrieve metadata via HTTP.

Comment: If you have httpGetEnabled you can write WMWebService.svc?wsdl and you will get metadata.

Comment: Is there any way through which my wcf service expose metadata without removing the mex endpoint with the same or any other configuration?

Comment: I guess the problem here is that WCF hosted in IIS doesn't like one HTTP based endpoint secured and one unsecured. I can't check this now. If I'm right the solution would be to demand Basic authentication for mex endpoint as well but it means custom binding.

Comment: Thanks Ladislav, my proble got resolved after I have used the same binding for mex endpoint also.. Thanks for the help!!