# Metadata request requires authentication in WCF even though service description page doesn't

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

I've set up a WCF service to require NTLM authentication using the following configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <customBinding>
            <binding name="BinarySecurityBinding">
                <binaryMessageEncoding/>
                <httpTransport authenticationScheme="Ntlm"/>
            </binding>
        </customBinding>
    </bindings>

    <services>
        <service name="Services.LogisticsServices" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
            <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="BinarySecurityBinding" contract="Services.ILogisticsServices" />
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I did this so that the applications that consume the web service are forced to log in because all my service's operations use impersonation (`[OperationBehavior(Impersonation = ImpersonationOption.Required)]`).

In IIS 7 I've enabled anonymous and Windows authentication.

When I visit `http://test.server/LogisticsServices.svc`, which hosts the service described above, I can see the default service description page anonymously. However, when Visual Studio tries to access `http://test.server/LogisticsServices.svc/$metadata` to generate a client proxy, the server is responding with HTTP code 401 and expecting authentication. Not only would I've expected the metadata to be available anonymously, but additionally, the server is not accepting the credentials I am giving it (even though, I know for a fact that they are correct).

Testing different configuration, I tried removing the `authenticationScheme` from my binding's transport, just to be able to generate the client proxy, but that results in an exception because the service's operations require impersonation (`[OperationBehavior(Impersonation = ImpersonationOption.Required)]`).

What am I missing in my service's configuration that would make the service's metadata available anonymously? I'm also open to suggestions if I'm approaching the whole thing wrong.

Comment: I've configured a test service with a similar configuration and don't have issues getting the metadata. From a browser, can you see the wsdl by entering this: http://test.server/LogisticsServices.svc?wsdl

Comment: I can see the WSDL. I've noticed that the credentials are only required if there is a slash after the .svc, e.g. http://test.server/LogisticsServices.svc/ or, of course, http://test.server/LogisticsServices.svc/$metadata

Comment: If you can get the WSDL then an awkward but simple solution is to create a file containing the WSDL (& a file for each wsdl:import referenced content) and place it on web server in the dev environment. Build your proxies using the URL to the file. You will have to update the WSDL & related files each time the service contract changes (awkward) but it does get around your authentication problem :)

Answer (score 0):

here is a similar discussion:

[Getting an Security setting exception while accessing a WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721809/getting-an-security-setting-exception-while-accessing-a-wcf-service)

Comment: I will in the production environment, when the metadata doesn't need to be available, but in the development environment, turning it off doesn't make the metadata availably anonymously, which is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

One way around this is not to use the autogenerated proxies.

In cases where we have control over both the server and the client we have found that it is much more productive to avoid using the autgenerated proxies.

A screencast of how to do this can be found here: http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=122

You could try imperative instead of declarative model, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730088.aspx

Comment: I agree, but unfortunately, I don't control the clients…